# Disable Full Keyboard Access for App

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, appkit

Can "Full Keyboard Access" (System Prefs -> Keyboard -> (Radio) All Controls) be controlled with some API? It causes major issues when this thing is on in my app (like buttons not working as expected etc ... it has some custom UI)

Regards,
Erik

Comment: What version of OS X are you using on what kind of machine?  And do you have some non-standard preference panel installed or perhaps something else?  I don't recall every seeing anything like what you describe and I don't see anything like it in any pref panels available on my systems.

Comment: Ned Deily: Like he says, it's in the Keyboard preference pane. On Snow Leopard, it's on the Keyboard Shortcuts tab in that pane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `nextValidKeyView` and `previousValidKeyView` in your custom view to return something sane, or set the view's `nextKeyView` and `previousKeyView` to specific views if detecting valid key views automatically isn't possible.

If Full Keyboard Access can't navigate your app correctly, then neither can anybody who can't use the mouse. Also, some of us really like Full Keyboard Access, and hate any app that either doesn't work properly under it or breaks it deliberately (and, from the user perspective, there is no difference).