# How do I programmatically determine if "Full Keyboard Access" mode is on in MacOS?

Tags: cocoa, accessibility

Full Keyboard Access mode is enabled or disabled in the Keyboard preference pane - it's referenced here:

[Efficiently subclassing standard Cocoa controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907017/efficiently-subclassing-standard-cocoa-controls)

and here:

[Disable Full Keyboard Access for App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964261/disable-full-keyboard-access-for-app)

but nowhere on the web have I found out how to determine, within my app, if Full Keyboard Access is enabled. I'm writing a custom radio control and want to allow tabbing into it iff Full Keyboard Access is on.

Answer (score 10):

In Mac OS X 10.6 or higher: -[NSApp isFullKeyboardAccessEnabled].

Answer (score 5):

As best I know this is undocumented. It is stored in `AppleKeyboardUIMode` in `NSGlobalDomain`:

```
defaults read -g AppleKeyboardUIMode
```

It's a bitfield, but I've never seen docs for it. "Full Keyboard Access" seems to toggle bit 1 (value=2).

The short is you should be able to fetch this from `NSUserDefaults` and bitmask it to find your answer, but it could change.