# How to receive space/tab keyDown event when (new) Full Keyboard Access setting is enabled?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit, accessibility-api

I am using a custom view class, which is a subclass of NSControl.
This view is a key view and needs to handle keyDown event including space/tab key.

But, when **Full Keyboard Access** is enabled at System Settings app > **Accessibility** > Keyboard, **the custom view cannot receive space/tab keyDown event**. MacOS seems to **interrupt** space/tab key event to control keyboard focus.

[Screenshot: Full Keyboard Access setting at Accessibility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khwrB.png)

On the other hand, NSTextView seems to be able to receive space/tab key events as follows even when Full Keyboard Access is enabled.

1. When user presses <kbd>tab</kbd> key from the previous view, keyboard focus moves to the NSTextView.
2. When user presses <kbd>tab</kbd> key at the NSTextView before inputing any letter, keyboard focus moves to the next view.
3. When user presses <kbd>tab</kbd> key at the NSTextView after inputing any letter, a tab letter is input.
4. When user presses <kbd>space</kbd> key at the NSTextView, a space letter is input.

I want to **do the same behavior as NSTextView**. But, I could not find the way to receive space/tab keyDown event when Full Keyboard Access is enabled.

How to receive keyDown event for space/tab key when Full Keyboard Access is enabled?

- I checked the following post, but it seems that the answer only explains how to set key view loop so that keyboard focus can be moved.

  [Disable Full Keyboard Access for App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964261/disable-full-keyboard-access-for-app)
- I confirmed this issue happens with macOS 13.2.1 and 12.5.
- There was an old "Full Keyboard Access" setting at System Settings app > **Keyboard** > Shortcuts in older macOS. This issue did not happen when the old Full Keyboard Access was enabled.

---

I tested the following minimal test code.

CustomView.m

```objc
@implementation CustomView
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyView {
    return YES;
}
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"keyDown");
}
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
    [[self window] makeFirstResponder:self];
}
- (BOOL)isAccessibilityElement {
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)isAccessibilityEnabled {
    return YES;
}
- (NSAccessibilityRole)accessibilityRole {
    return NSAccessibilityTextFieldRole;
}
@end
```

CustomView.h

```objc
@interface CustomView : NSControl
@end
```

ViewController.m

```objc
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[[self view] window] makeFirstResponder:self.customView1];
}
@end
```

Expected result: The custom view **can** receive space/tab keyDown event.

Actual result: The custom view **cannot** receive space/tab keyDown event.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this issue after I implement the following methods of NSAccessibility API. (I am not sure which methods are mandatory to resolve this issue. At least, accessibilityValue and setAccessibilityValue are mandatory.)

```
isAccessibilityElement
isAccessibilityEnabled
accessibilityValue
setAccessibilityValue
isAccessibilityFocused
accessibilityInsertionPointLineNumber
accessibilityNumberOfCharacters
accessibilitySelectedText
accessibilitySelectedTextRange
setAccessibilitySelectedTextRange
accessibilitySelectedTextRanges
accessibilityVisibleCharacterRange
accessibilityStringForRange
accessibilityAttributedStringForRange
accessibilityFrameForRange
accessibilityLineForIndex
accessibilityRangeForIndex
accessibilityStyleRangeForIndex
accessibilityRangeForLine
accessibilityFocusedUIElement
accessibilityHitTest
```